find the position a mobile when $x'(t)=2 y'(t)$
A mobile is moving along the graph of $f(x)= \ln(x)$ , find the position of the mobile at the point in time when the rate of change of the abscissa is twice the rate of change of the ordinate.
My attempt to solve it .
Since both $x,y$ are now functions of time we can rewrite them as $x(t),y(t)$
We are given that at a specific point in time the speed to $x(t)$ is double of that of $y(t)$
in other words , at a certain point in time $t_0$ we have
$$x'(t_0)=2 y'(t_0)$$
We take the derivative of $y(t)=f(x(t))$
$$y'(t)=\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}
$$
and we get that $x(t)= \frac{x'(t)}{y'(t)} $
When $t=t_0 \implies x(t_0)= \frac{x'(t_0)}{y'(t_0)}= \frac{2y'(t)}{y'(t)}=2$
so the mobile is at $x=2$ at $t_0$
How do I continue ? Am I even on the rigth path? Any help would be appreciated

You are 99% there! You know $x(t_0)$ and you know that $y=f(x)$ so you know $y(t_0)$.

PS What is a "mobile"?

@Blitzer A mobile is something that is moving -for lack of a better word. So do I just say $x(t_0)=2 \implies y(t_0)=f(x(t_0))=f(2)=\ln(2) $ and the position is $(x,y)=(2, \ln(2) )$?

That sounds right to me.
I think more common words would be "a particle" or "an object".

That's true , I translated it from Greek and that is the exact meaning but it really does not sound right . I'll use one of those words from now on. Thanks for helping!
